# Issue with posting via Ajax to MySql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, asynchronous

The Data base is not updated although I am pretty sure my code is good (did several tests). So there must be an issue (async, etc.). I need help to figure out what is wrong.

Here is my Ajax call (by the press of a Save button, it is tested and it fires well):

```
$.ajax({  
url: "../../../../admin/includes/classes/class.article_front_Post.php",     
type: "POST",
data: {
        'articleid': $articleid,
        'contenu': $contenu,
        'name': $name 
      }

});
```

And here is the content of the ... front_Post.php file:

```
include_once('../../../../init.php');

$articleid  = $_GET['articleid'];
$contenu  = $_GET['contenu'];
$name  = $_GET['name'];

// $name  = 'special1';            
// $contenu  = '<p>test</p>';
// $articleid  = '17';
// above to test the update (it works)

mysql_query("

UPDATE al_articles SET $name='$contenu'
WHERE (ArticleID='$articleid')

") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: what is an error ??

Comment: There was no error - thanks it is solved now. See below.

Comment: Be advised:  `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and have been removed from PHP 7, having been replaced with `myslqi_*` and `PDO` functions which are much more secure when using prepared statements and bound parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax is using "POST" :

```
$.ajax({  
url: "../../../../admin/includes/classes/class.article_front_Post.php",     
type: "POST",    //<====================================================!!!!
data: {
        'articleid': $articleid,
        'contenu': $contenu,
        'name': $name 
      }
});
```

But your PHP is using "GET", so, replace the "GET" by "POST" :

```
include_once('../../../../init.php');

$articleid  = $_POST['articleid']; //<===============================
$contenu  = $_POST['contenu'];     //<===============================
$name  = $_POST['name'];           //<===============================

// $name  = 'special1';            
// $contenu  = '<p>test</p>';
// $articleid  = '17';
// above to test the update (it works)

mysql_query("

UPDATE al_articles SET $name='$contenu'
WHERE (ArticleID='$articleid')

") or die(mysql_error());
```

Or replace the "POST" by "GET" in your ajax. Anyway, GET parameters can be seen on the URL, so I recommend POST.

Comment: Yes! thanks! Works now! (I will do my homework to understand The Post and Get thing!.

Comment: Just did, thanks again! - there is a time out that prevents to do it too early.